# How would use the POST method to do a postback? [JS] [ROBLOX]

Tags: javascript, jquery, postback, roblox

**Situation :**

I am trying to use $.post to post to this site but it is using ASP.NET postbacks and I am not sure how to use it.

Site : http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=1

Go down to the bottom of the page where you see the inventory and click 'Gear'. I want to simulate that (switch from the default tab to the 'Gear' tab) with code from the console, to be able to get from JavaScript the content of that tab.

**Here is my code :**

```
 var Link = "http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=1"
    $.get(Link).always(function(Data){
        var Viewstate = Data.match(/id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.+)"/)[1]
        var EventValidation = Data.match(/id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.+)"/)[1]
        $.post(Link,{
            "ctl00$ScriptManager" : "ctl00$cphRoblox$rbxUserAssetsPane$upUserAssetsPane|ctl00$cphRoblox$rbxUserAssetsPane$AssetCategoryRepeater$ctl02$AssetCategorySelector",
            "__EVENTTARGET" : "ctl00$cphRoblox$rbxUserAssetsPane$AssetCategoryRepeater$ctl02$AssetCategorySelector",
            "ctl00$cphRoblox$rbxFavoritesPane$AssetCategoryDropDownList" : "9",
            "__VIEWSTATE" : Viewstate,
            "__EVENTVALIDATION" : EventValidation,
            "__ASYNCPOST" : true,
        },function(Data){console.log(Data)}).always(function(Data2){
            console.log(Data2)
        })
    })
```

Comment: Could someone please help?